# How to push new controller without changing the NavigationItem's title?

Tags: ios, swift

Simple question but I couldn't find any solution. I want to push new ViewController with NavigationController
In vc1 I have title "xxx" and I am pushing to vc2

```
let vc2 = MyViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I want vc2 to have the same title as vc1 but without the changing title animation when vc2 is being pushed

Comment: You have to set it in VC2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller?language=objc#topics "The Middle Item"

You can also try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543702/animate-nav-bar-title-text-change

Answer (score 1):

First: You have to create a super view controller and set the title like this

```
   class MainViewController: UIViewController {

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                self.title = "Commmon name"

            }
    }
```

Second: Inherit super view controller in every view controller where you want to same Title or every this which you want same in every view controller.

```
class FirstViewController: MainViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
}

class SecondViewController: MainViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
}
```

Now you can push then you will get same title in every view controller which one is inherit super view controller like above example

Answer (score 0):

you can set same title in two controllers, for example:

```
class VcOne : UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.title = "Title"
        }
}

class VcTwo : UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.title = "Title"
        }
}
```

hope it can help you